# conditional formating IF column b is empty then column c will be no value or zero

Tags: excel-formula

I have three columns

```
  A       B         C
Slots   Remarks   Amount
10        x        must be zero (coz amount got formula [slot*100])
20        /        2,000 [answer for 20slots x 100]
10        /        1,000
 5        x            -
```

That's why I think of conditional formatting.

TQ

Comment: Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am assuming you are using "x" to indicate a blank cell in column B

Answer (score 0):

In C2 use the following formula and copy down

```
=IF(B2="","",A2*100)
```

or

```
=IF(B2="",0,A2*100)
```

Update for checking for x in column b

If you want to to have 0 or blank, check to see if B2="x"

```
=IF(B2="x","",A2*100)
```

or

```
=IF(B2="x",0,A2*100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. ;)

Comment: If in SLOTS got number and next column is "X" amount still got answer shows; supposed must be empty or zero only.

Comment: your title said if column B was empty, not if column b had an x in it